# How to add a node iteratively in a different position of the graph using network x

Tags: python, networking, networkx

Initially I have one node at position (0, 0). Now in next iteration with node size 1 and 2 I want my node 2 position at (1, 0) and add edge between them and then  add edge between them. So after 2nd iteration I will have a graph of edges (0, 0), (1, 0). Now I want use this data at my next iteration of adding node and add node and add edges such that i will have graph of edges (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0). Can anyone provide a sample code for this using network x. I am new to python as well as network x!

I have tried using the for loop but i did not use it as a initial point for next iteration

Answer (score 0):

Try if this code helps solve what you are asking for

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create an empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Initial node position
pos = {(0, 0): (0, 0)}

# Add initial node
G.add_node((0, 0))

# Iterate over each iteration
for i in range(1, 3):  # Change the range to specify the number of iterations
    # Add new node and edge from previous node
    new_node = (i, 0)
    G.add_node(new_node)
    G.add_edge((i-1, 0), new_node)
    # Update node position
    pos[new_node] = (i, 0)

# Draw the graph
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='skyblue', 
font_size=10)
plt.title('Graph after 2 iterations')
plt.show()
```

hope this answers your question If there is anything else leave a comment.